# plsql function - return based on number passed

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm expecting different values based on input passed onto my plsql function. Apologies as I'm pretty new to plsql...

Range
1
2
3
.
.
9
45
46
86

My function as below:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE function get_ext (p_str varchar2) 
return varchar2 
is

cursor ext is
select range from table where length(range)>1;

v_str varchar2(100);
v_ext number;
v_length number := 0;
v_range varchar2(200);

BEGIN
open ext;
fetch ext into v_range;

v_str := p_str;
v_str := trim(substr(v_str,1,4));
v_length := length(v_str);

for i in 1..v_length loop
   BEGIN      
     v_ext := substr(v_str, i,1);                
   EXCEPTION
   WHEN OTHERS THEN
     RETURN p_str;
  END;
end loop;

RETURN
case when ext%FOUND then substr(v_str,1,2)
else substr(v_str,1,1)
end;
close ext;

EXCEPTION
WHEN OTHERS THEN
RETURN 'Err';
END;
```

It is always returning the first two digits of the passed parameter but not the 1 digit I'm expecting when not found.

testing the function

```
select get_ext('4588') from dual
```

returns 45

```
select get_ext('1822') from dual
```

returns 18 whereas I'm expecting it to return 1

Thanks in advance

Comment: the problem should be related to the row `case when ext%FOUND then substr(v_str,1,2)`

Comment: You're doing a lot of unnecessary things; one of the most suspicious is the FOR loop. What is its purpose? V_EXT will always be the last character in the string, but you never use V_EXT variable after that. Furthermore, EXT cursor is fetched only once, regardless of how many rows in the TABLE satisfy the condition (i.e. having length of RANGE > 1). It would help if you described what you have and what you'd want to return as a result.

Comment: I have difficulties understanding the task. Are you trying to return the longest substring found at the beginning of the string? So for the string '4588' there is no '4588' in the table, no '458', but '45' and you return this. For '1822' there is no '1822' in the table, no '182', no '18', but '1', so you return '1'. Yes?

Comment: I don't see any correlation between the cursor and the return statement except checking that if the cursor is empty, just `substr` first character if the passed string and the function is working well. Not sure what is your actual question coz I see no issue in your code.

Comment: @Littlefoot - How do I fetch the 2nd, 3rd values from the cursor? I have 1, 2, 3, 4...8, 9, 45, 46, 47, 86 in my table column. If I pass 1234 into the function I expect it to return 1. If I pass 4634 I expect it to return 46.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner - the passed number is not in the table. The table values are either 1 digit or 2 digits. If the passed value's first two digits match with the table value then return the 2 digit number. Otherwise return the 1 digit of the passed value. Hope it makes sense.

Comment: Then it's just as I said. You want the longest matching range number. (Only that your table doesn't contain three or four digit range numbers, but the same rule applies.)

Comment: I have posted an answer. However, I notice now, that you completely forgot to ask any question in your request. Are you asking us to tell you why your code doesn't work or are you looking for a good way to approach the task?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner - I'm looking for a good approach. Why the code doesn't work would help also as I'm new to plsql. btw, your KEEP LAST code works as I'm using 11g. I need to get it is a function tough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You find matching range values with `LIKE`. As of Oracle 12c you could then use `FETCH FIRST` to get the match with the longest length:

```
select range
from mytable
where :str like range || '%'
order by length(range) desc
fetch first row only;
```

Or use `KEEP LAST`, which is also available in earlier versions:

```
select max(range) keep (dense_rank last order by length(range))
from mytable
where :str like range || '%';
```

And if you like this better, then put this query in a PL/SQL function. But it's not necessary of course, you can just as well run the query directly.

Comment: Thanks Thorsten - I've added a function and passed values are returned as expected. Thanks for your time.